# Exception thrown: 'System.Xml.XPath.XPathException' in System.Xml.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt

whenever I tried to save my post, I would get an error like this

> Exception thrown: 'System.Xml.XPath.XPathException' in System.Xml.dll

For your information : 
I am sending a response query string from a XSLT file,

```
 <td><a class="btn btn-default" href="EditPost.aspx?pid={@pid}">Edit</a> <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">Delete</a></td>
```

Next, a web form will capture the query string and read the selected post from my xml data.

```
 protected void Update_btn_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string new_title = newtitle.Text.ToString();
        string new_description = update_des.Value.ToString();
        string postid = Request.QueryString["pid"];
        string docPath = @"~/Data/blog_post.xml";
         XmlDocument xml_doc = new XmlDocument();

        xml_doc.Load(Server.MapPath(docPath));

        XmlNode elemList = xml_doc.SelectSingleNode("/Posts/post[@pid=" + postid + "]/title");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(elemList);
    }
```

My XML data :

```
<Posts>
    <post pid="pid2623">
    <title>Test</title>
    <description>Test</description>
    <subtitle>Test</subtitle>
    <date>7/29/2018 12:00:00 AM</date>
    <author>est</author>
  </post>
</Posts>
```

Comment: You are sending a string not a filename or URL.  So use xml_doc.Parse() instead of xml_doc.Load().

Answer (score 1):

You can treat a value like `pid2623` as a string in XPath but for that you need to wrap it in quotes e.g. `xml_doc.SelectSingleNode("/Posts/post[@pid='" + postid + "']/title")` or `xml_doc.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("/Posts/post[@pid='{0}']/title", postid))`.